# How to resize Chart.JS element in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chart.js

I have a React component `Webstats` which returns a Doughnut chart from **react-chartjs-2** library. Here is how the code looks like:

```
const Webstats = () => {
  //code to create chart.
  return <Doughnut data={pd} />;
}
```

I use this component inside another component called `Dashboard`. I want to display the chart alongside a Logout button. Both should be in the same row. I use `flex` property of css for this purpose.

```
const rowC = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row"
};

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div style={rowC}>
      <Webstats />
      <Link to="/">
        <div>
          <button onClick={auth.logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

But the problem is that, chart size is too big as compared to logout button.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to make chart size small, around 30% of the width of `<div style={rowC}>`. I tried these things:

```
return <Doughnut data={pd} width="30%"/>;
```

and

```
return (
    <div style={rowC}>
      <Webstats width="30%" />
      // rest of html
)
```

and also

```
return (
    <div width="30%">
      <Doughnut data={pd} />
    </div>
  );
```

But none of this gives me the desired result. How to I resize the chart to 30% of the width (and height auto adjusted) of the `<div style={rowC}>`?

Comment: Are you using a CSS library like [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)? If so, you could use [columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/), which would simply what you're trying to do quite significantly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [documentation for ChartJS](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2#custom-size) states that you need to set `maintainAspectRatio` to false for it to use the width and height props that you pass into your chart.

> In order for Chart.js to obey the custom size you need to set `maintainAspectRatio` to false.

```
<Doughnut
  data={data}
  width={"30%"}
  options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
/>
```

Comment: That didn't quite fix it for me. For anyone else stuck, you may need to create a dedicated container (eg ```<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <Doughnut/>
</div>``` )
See this documentation section for more info:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Answer (score 4):

Doing the following works for me:

1. set height and width on the `<Doughnut />` component.
2. Set the maintainAspectRation to false.

Here is what the outcome looks like:

```
<Doughnut
  data={data}
  height="200px"
  width="200px"
  options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in `div` Container and set width and height.

Ex:

```
<div style={{height:"60vh",position:"relative", marginBottom:"1%", padding:"1%"}}>
     <Doughnut options={options} data={chartData} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.2"
```

docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/general/responsive.html

OPTIONS ARE MOST IMPORTANT:

```
const options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    aspectRatio: 1
    }

    <div style={{width: '500px'}}>   
            <Doughnut data={chartData} options={options}  />
    </div>
```

so now what ever size you put into Parent Div, e.g. 500px, will be the size of the Chart

Comment: @Tarun you should enmark this as the answer since all of the above won't work

Comment: aspectRatio: 1 work for me, for my case i need to set it to 2

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to set the width manually using the style property and to add maintainAspectRatio: false to options like so:

```
<Pie
    style={{ width: "500px" }}
    options={{
      maintainAspectRatio: false}} />
```